# Django - using regex in urls.py to pass values

Tags: python, django

I just ran into a problem..

I'm trying to build a website at the moment with different pages.
So I created a django app called pages, with the following fields:

- title
- text
- URL

The idea is, that users can create new pages and delete existing ones and it actually affects the navigation in real time.

So in my urls.py I wanted to handle this somehow like this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *


urlpatterns = patterns('',
  (r'^pages/(/w)', pages.views.display_content),
)
```

For example there could be a page with URL property "page1", then "page1" should be stored by (/w) and passed over to pages.views.display_content, which then would display the corresponding data. The "page1" page would be accessible through domain.com/pages/page1.

However, as I'm not really good with regex, I think I really need your help.
I would be really happy if someone could explain to me how I have to write my URL rule for this..

Good Night :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition, you could name the parameter that will be captured and passed to your view function with this notation:

```
...
(r'^pages/(?P<page_name>\w+)', 'pages.views.display_content'),
...
```

So you can access it with that name in your view function.
Its header should look like this:

```
def display_content(request, page_name):
    ...
```